# Issue when converting SQL to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I am attempting to convert a SQL stored procedure to LINQ to do some performance testing (trying to figure out if using LINQ in some of our methods will speed things up at all)

I am fairly new to doing anything in LINQ so I am just modifying examples in books / online to suit my needs and am stuck on something.

I have this code so far:

```
DIM TicketID as INTEGER = 1

DIM s = 
FROM User in PersonnelTbl 
WHERE !(from t in tblSupportTicketNotifications where t.TicketID = TicketID select t.EmployeeID).Contains(User.EmployeeID)
Select user
```

Im not sure why but I get an Identifier expected error message on the Where clause line. Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Cheers

I've based my code so far on this example:

```
var query = 

    from c in dc.Customers 

    where !(from o in dc.Orders 

            select o.CustomerID)

           .Contains(c.CustomerID) 

    select c;
```

This is what I am trying to convert

```
CREATE PROCEDURE spGetEmployeesToBeNotified  
(  
 @TicketID INT  
)  
AS   
BEGIN  

 SELECT   
  ID,   
  FirstName,  
  Surname,  
  FirstName+' '+Surname As FullName,   
  WorkEmail,   
  0 AS Checked  
 FROM   
  PersonnelTbl   
 WHERE   
  ID NOT IN(SELECT EmployeeID FROM tblSupportTicketNotifications WHERE TicketID = @TicketID)  
 AND  
  (FirstName IS NOT NULL   
  AND   
   FirstName <> ''   
  AND   
   Surname IS NOT NULL   
  AND   
   Surname <> '')  

 UNION  
 SELECT   
  person.ID,  
  person.FirstName,  
  person.Surname,  
  person.FirstName +' '+person.Surname As FullName,  
  person.WorkEmail,  
  1 AS Checked  
 FROM  
  PersonnelTbl person  
 JOIN  
  tblSupportTicketNotifications notify  
 ON  
  person.ID = notify.EmployeeID  
 WHERE  
  TicketID = @TicketID  
 ORDER BY   
  FirstName ASC,   
  Surname ASC  
END
```

Comment: If you are interested in orm tool performance check this out...

http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/

Basically linq to sql will be alot slower unless you use compiled queries and then it will still be slower than hand coded stuff using ado.

Comment: Sorry I just noticed the ! should be Not as its VB not C#!  Should have spotted that a lot sooner!

Comment: @jsobo thanks I'll check that out. Performance is really the issue here we have a few more complex stored procs and I figured I might be able to improve some of the system by converting parts to Linq

Comment: You could improve your performance (Possibly) by converting the "where not in" to a left join with a where clause looking for nulls...

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a go, tbh this proc isnt one of the ones im going to need to improve, its just one of the simpler ones I figured might be easier for me to convert whilst learning LINQ

Comment: you should ask how to rewrite that query as a SQL question... I'm sure you will get great answers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an association between User and SupportTicketNotifications, you could try the following which should use an Exists clause rather than In. You can then profile the differences in SQL to see which one actually works faster (or if the SQL engine optimizes them to the same things.)

```
DIM TicketID as INTEGER = 1 

DIM s =  
FROM User in PersonnelTbl  
WHERE Not User.SupportTicketNotifications.Any(Function(t) t.TicketID = TicketID)

' The Select is optional in VB if you are just returning the item you are selecting.
```

Regarding performance with LINQ to SQL as compared to raw ADO, you may want to check out http://blogs.msdn.com/ricom/archive/2007/06/22/dlinq-linq-to-sql-performance-part-1.aspx. As you are learning LINQ, you should make an effort to profile what you are doing in any regard to help you learn what's happening and where you need to make performance improvements (including using Stored Procs/custom ADO where necessary).

Answer (score 1):

Linq-2-sql will NEVER outperform a stored procedure.

In the end, all what Linq-2-sql does is give you a more object oriented approach but in the end it IS SQL that is being send to the database. So if you put the same SQL in the stored procedure it by definition is at least equally fast.

Answer (score 0):

! is a C# operator. You want "Not" instead for VB.Net.